# Error while reading csv file comma separated file size 65MB

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
pd.read_csv("abc.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1",sep=",",engine="python")
```

Error :

> ParserError: ',' expected after '"'

Why is it showing error inspite of `engine="python"`?

Comment: please [read this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: yet it is not working bro

Comment: i read from there

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so that is why I use this way to help you. Could you provide anymore information? Why do you specify `encoding` and `engine` as such?

Does the error also occur when executing `pd.read_csv("abc.csv")`?

Comment: yes it occours and the error is following : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 4: invalid start byte

Comment: I'm not familiar with the error, but what happens when you execute ```pd.read_csv("abc.csv",encoding="utf-8",sep=",",engine="python")```. Does the error still occur?